# Android TTS for Thai language

Tags: gratis, android, speech-synthesis

I am looking for an Android TTS (Text To Speech) app for Thai language.

Free, ideally open source.

Your perception of speech quality, and ideally samples of generated speech to evaluate quality, would be appreciated.